# Importing sequence into HTML formatting with python

Tags: python, html, spacing

I'm trying to import an sequence between 1 and 999 letters from a text file, using :

```
input_file.open(textfile.txt)
sequence = input_file.read()
inputfile_close()
```

I then open a new HTML file to write in with :

```
output_file.open(new.html, 'w')
```

I then have the HTML formatting written into the new file using:

```
output_file.write(-formatting-)
```

I'm currently using :

```
    if character == 'A' or character == 'G' or character == 'I' or character == 'L' or character == 'P' or character == 'V' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:white;">' + character + '</font>')    
    if character == 'F' or character == 'Y' or character == 'W' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:green;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
    if character == 'D' or character == 'E' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:orange;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
    if character == 'H' or character == 'K' or character == 'R' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:red;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
    if character == 'S' or character == 'T' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:purple;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
    if character == 'C' or character== 'M' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:yellow;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
    if character == 'N' or character == 'Q' :
        output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:blue;">' + character + '</font>') # now we put the text we've read from the text file in
```

to color code each individual letter.

My problem is that I need the sequence to have a space after every 10th letter, and a new line after every 60th letter.
Both the sequence and the numbering need to be monospaced.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If any further information is needed, please ask.

I've made a picture with the coding [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp6sU.jpg). 
The attached coding is what I'm currently using.

Thank you

Comment: Pro tip for cutting down on those long `if` cases: `if character in ('A', 'G', 'I', 'L', 'P', 'V'):` make it a lot easier to read. I'd also consider placing all your modified characters in a list, and extract blocks like so: `formatted_characters[0:10] + '&nbsp;'` and just do a normal counter for the 60:th letter and insert your break.

Comment: @Torxed Can you give me an example of a counter?
Why would it be beneficial to have them in a list and then extract them?

Comment: Jacob, you would do it by not writing to the file directly via `output_file.write(...)`, but rather store your result in `result = ''.join(formatted_characters)` and then do `for i in range(0, len(result), 60): output_file.write(result[i:i+60] + '<br>')` or something similar.

Comment: @Torxed So the sequence I import would be the formatted characters? or would they be a seperate entity?

Comment: `I need the sequence to have a space after every 10th letter, and a new line after every 60th letter.` - was this part of your problem not solved a few days ago?

Comment: @asongtoruin Yes It was, I was suggested to [use](http://imgur.com/a/iHeti). 

But I unfortunately couldn't get it to work with my HTML formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you read the `sequence` and write the html in a `for` loop? Write the formatted sequence to a string first and subsequently write the whole string to the html.

With the modulo operator `%` you can add the space/linebreak.

```
formatted_seq = ""
count = 0
for character in sequence:
    if character in 'AGILPV':
        bg = "white"
    elif character in 'FYW':
        bg = "green"
    elif character in 'DE':
        bg = "orange"
    elif character in 'HKB':
        bg = "red"
    elif character in 'ST':
        bg = "purple"
    elif character in 'CM':
        bg = "yellow"
    elif character in 'NQ':
        bg = "blue"

    formatted_seq += '<font style="background-color:' + bg + ';">' + character + '</font>'

    count += 1
    if count%60 == 0:
        formatted_seq += '<br>'
    elif count%10 == 0:
        formatted_seq += '&nbsp;'
```

Comment: I've tried to use this but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I've attempted to use this part instead of my version:
 for character in (sequence) :
  if character in ('A', 'G', 'I', 'L', 'P', 'V') :
   output_file.write ('<font style="background-color:white;">' + character + '</font>') 
  Is that the correct place for it?

Comment: @JacobSørensen yep that's right. So you can replace the `formatted_seq += ` with `output_file.write()` and instead of collecting the string in a variable you are writing directly to the output file. But my thinking was to clean up the code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: Hi, I'm still having some problems with getting your coding to work, am I doing something wrong? I've got a picture [here](http://imgur.com/a/WjwQS).
I don't quite understand how to use formatted_seq += instead of output_file.write(), do I have to save my sequence as something different?

Comment: @JacobSørensen 1. You close `input_file` before you read from it. The variable `sequence` cannot read the input file if you close it. So close it after the `for` loop. 2. You have to write the resulting string `formatted_seq` to the output file by `output_file.write(formatted_seq)`